# Keeping track of master volume slider PlayerPref in another scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm quite new to Unity and just started learning UI and made a volume slider in a settings scene. I've learnt how to use those 2 functions to save the PlayerPref of the volume so whenever the player enters the settings scene again, the volume will be saved from last time.
However, I wonder how you can change it so it will do the same but on the main menu? So that way the player doesn't need to go back to settings for it to apply.
The code:

```
`using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SettingsMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Slider volumeSlider;

    void Start()
    {
        keepVolumeValue();
        GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Music").GetComponent<MusicManager>().playMusic();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
            SceneManager.LoadScene("MainMenu");
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("volume", volumeSlider.value);
    }

    public void keepVolumeValue()
    {
        volumeSlider.value = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("volume", volumeSlider.value);
    }

    public void setVolume(float volume)
    {
        mainMixer.SetFloat("volume", Mathf.Log10(volume)*30f);
    }`
```

Ty for any help

Comment: `I wonder how you can change it so it will do the same but on the main menu` .. simply do the same on the main menu then? I don't really understand the question ...

Comment: I tried but the setting menu is a whole different scene, so the volume slider isn't accessible from the main menu, at least I don't know how to access it yet that way

Comment: But in your main menu you see to only want to get the float value from player prefs (`PlayerPrefs.GetFloat`) and not the slider itself ... otherwise what is the settings menu good for?

Comment: Oh so I get an AudioMixer there too and use "mainMixer.setFloat("volume", PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("volume"))"?

Comment: AudioMixer is an asset -> you can just use the same mixer for both scenes and yes simply fetch the volume once when starting your app, you don't even have to do it for every new scene since once set the AudioMixer will keep it's settings across scenes

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant an AudioMixer reference. Also that means I can just do it only on the main menu, as it will be saved across the different scenes right?

Comment: Well I've added this line: mixer.SetFloat("volume", PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("volume"));
It's in the Main Menu script in the Start() function, however it keeps resetting the volume to default when going to the main menu.